# Retrieving contacts

Tags: android

I have tried to get phone number also but i didn't no how to get using this code . This the code i am using please tell how to get number by same code for same id

```
// method to get name, contact id, and birthday
private Cursor getContactsBirthdays() {
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE
    };

    String where =
            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "= ? AND " +
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE + "=" + 
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY;
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { 
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
    };
    String sortOrder = null;
    return managedQuery(uri, projection, where, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
}

// iterate through all Contact's Birthdays and print in log
Cursor cursor = getContactsBirthdays();
int bDayColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE);
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String bDay = cursor.getString(bDayColumn);
    Log.d(TAG, "Birthday: " + bDay);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to simply dump all birthdays and all phones to the log, or do you want for EACH BIRTHDAY to also write the phone number associated with that contact?

Comment: i want phone number assiociated with that birthday contact

Answer (score 0):

You need to first get a list of all contact-ids that has birthdays, then query for the phones of all those contacts, and then print the combined results.

```
Cursor cursor = getContactsBirthdays();

// get contact-ids for phones query
List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    ids.add(cursor.getString(1));
}
String[] projection = new String[] { Phone.NUMBER, Phone.CONTACT_ID };

StringBuilder where = new StringBuilder(Data.MIMETYPE + " = " Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + " AND " + Contacts.CONTACT_ID + " IN (");
for (String id : ids) {
    where.append(id).append(",");
}
where.deleteCharAt(where.length() - 1);
where.append(")");


Cursor cur2 = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, where.toString(), null, null);
Map<Long, String> contactIdToPhone = new HashMap<>();
while (cur2.moveToNext()) {
    contactIdToPhone.put(cur2.get(1), cur2.get(0));
}
cur2.close();

cursor.moveToPosition(-1);
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    Long id = cursor.getLong(1);
    Log.i(TAG, "Birthday: id=" + id + ", name=" + cursor.getString(0) + ", date=" + cursor.getString(2) + ", phone=" + contactIdToPhone.get(id));
}
cursor.close();
```

Comment: where.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1); Error in sb

Comment: it's a typo, change to `where.length()`

Comment: From this section i m getting error in code and i get id and contact name which has birthday date in previous code but i didn't get only phone number

Comment: not sure i understand your last comment, what do you see in the log?